# Junit test with jsonPath doesn't find the matching content

Tags: java, junit5, jsonpath

I have this simple unit test:-

```
@Test
void getCityName() throws Exception {
    when(weatherService.getWeatherByCity(capitalize(TestData.getWeather().getCity())))
            .thenReturn(TestData.getWeatherList());

 mockMvc.perform(get(WeatherController.WEATHER+WeatherController.GET_WEATHER_BY_CITY+"/espoo"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    /*  it doesn't work if uncommented.  
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.city")
                    .value("espoo"))
   */
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

}
```

`.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());` prints out this:-

```
    MockHttpServletResponse:
        Status = 200
    Error message = null
        Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
    Content type = application/json
            Body = [{"id":null,"city":"espoo","country":null,"description":null,"currentTemp":0.0,"feelsLike":3.3,"minTemp":2.2,"maxTemp":5.5,"tempLimit":3.0,"frequency":5,"frequencyUnit":"SECOND","uri":"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=espoo&units=metric&APPID=5536a9b0c84d081997982254c24fc53a"}]
    Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
        Cookies = []
```

I can see there is `"city":"espoo"`. How do I match this. I tired:-

```
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.city")
 .value("espoo"))
```

It give error:-

DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $.size()
DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $['city']

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.city"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is of type Array:

```
[{"id":null,"city":"espoo","country":null,"description":null,"currentTemp":0.0,"feelsLike":3.3,"minTemp":2.2,"maxTemp":5.5,"tempLimit":3.0,"frequency":5,"frequencyUnit":"SECOND","uri":"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=espoo&units=metric&APPID=5536a9b0c84d081997982254c24fc53a"}]
```

Therefore you will need to choose the index first, then attribute `$[0].city`

```
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].city", is(espoo)))
```

=== Edited ===

Please try:

```
  .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].city").value("espoo"));
```

Comment: yes, it must the correct answer. But when I tired `.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].city", is("espoo")))` I got compiler error as "java: incompatible types: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers cannot be converted to org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher"

Comment: Please see edit @MasiBoo